# AHBottomNavigation always on front of FloatingActionButton

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm trying to create a layout with an FAB on top of the bottom navigation menu, but the menu always stays above the button. :(

My layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    tools:context="com.example.mytest.money.MainActivity">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/card_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:layout_height="110dp"
        android:padding="15dp"
        card_view:cardElevation="2dp"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="Test" />

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/bottom_navigation"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:foreground="@color/colorBackground">
    </ScrollView>

    <com.aurelhubert.ahbottomnavigation.AHBottomNavigation
        android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:selectedBackgroundVisible="false"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/create_gain_expense"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|center"
        android:layout_margin="15dp"
        android:layout_above="@id/bottom_navigation"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_add_white_24dp"
        app:fabSize="normal" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

What I expect:

[Expectation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/umvpQ.png)

What I got:

[Reality](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eTaEn.png)

What can I do to change this? :D

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I guess the problem is, `AHBottomNavigation` has higher `elevation` than `FloatingActionButton` that's why its showing above the `FloatingActionButton`.

`FloatingActionButton` has default `6dp` elevation and the default `elevation` of `AHBottomNavigation` is `8dp`(From `AHBottomNavigation` [source](https://github.com/aurelhubert/ahbottomnavigation/blob/master/ahbottomnavigation/src/main/res/values/dimens.xml))

**Try setting more higher `elevation` to `FloatingActionButton`:**

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/create_gain_expense"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|center"
    android:layout_margin="15dp"
    android:layout_above="@id/bottom_navigation"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_add_white_24dp"
    app:fabSize="normal"
    app:elevation="12dp"
    app:borderWidth="0dp" />
```

**#.** You can also use `android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView` instead of `AHBottomNavigation`.

**Below is an Orthographic view of app structure:**

[image]

See [documentation](https://material.io/guidelines/components/bottom-navigation.html#bottom-navigation-specs).

Hope this will help~

Answer (score 0):

[image: ss]

**Try this code :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/container">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/card_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:layout_height="110dp"
        android:padding="15dp"
        card_view:cardElevation="2dp"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="Test" />

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/bottom_navigation"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:foreground="@color/white">
    </ScrollView>

    <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="56dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:background="@color/green"
        app:itemIconTint="@color/white"
        app:itemTextColor="@color/white"
        android:id="@+id/bottomnav"
        app:menu="@menu/main">


    </android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/create_gain_expense"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|center"
        android:layout_margin="15dp"
        android:layout_above="@id/bottom_navigation"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_add_black_24dp"
        app:fabSize="normal"
        app:elevation="12dp"
        app:borderWidth="0dp" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

> **You can replace this bottom navigation bar with your own.**